# Почему не работает justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css

Подскажите почему не работает?

```css
.wrapper__achivments{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper__achivments__text-title{
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 64px;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
.wrapper__achivments__text-subtitle{
    margin-top: -25px;
}

.achivments__row__1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.achivments__download{
    display: flex;
}
.achivment__download-text{
    margin-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper__achivments">
                    <div class="wrapper__achivments__text">
                        <h3 class="wrapper__achivments__text-title">Наши 18 лет достижений</h3>
                        <p class="wrapper__achivments__text-subtitle">С нашими суперспособностями мы достигли этого</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper__achivments__cards">
                        <div class="achivments__row__1">
                            <div class="achivments__download">
                                <img src="img/01.svg" alt="Robust workflow" class="achivments-logo">
                                <div class="achivment__download-text">
                                    <h5 class="achivment-title">10,000+</h5>
                                    <p class="achivment-subtitle">Downloads per day</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Запустил этот пример — всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Из описания проблемы не понятна задача.
Но если вы хотите разместить контейнеры внутри `.wrapper__achivments` в одну линию, то уберите `flex-wrap: wrap` - это свойство позволяет размещать блоки в несколько линий.